# Field change tracking in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, change-tracking

Is there a way to find out what field has been changed on my object.

Sample problem : when some date field is changed and the changes are being saved custom some custom logic should be applied to related objects.

I am trying to do it before `context.SaveChanges();` but `ObjectStateManager` doesn't give me all the information I need.

Comment: How are your domain objects generated? You might want to check out self tracking entities, the generated code has an object change tracker and event hooks for property modification you might want to use.

Comment: I'm using POCO's, but the thing is that I have to respond to specific field change. And ObjectStateManager doesn't provide that functionality as far as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to use `ObjectStateManager` for that? You have entities which have getter and setter so simply put that logic trigger in setter. You can also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your entity and handle event when your required property changes outside of the entity.

Otherwise you must use `ObjectStateManager` get `ObjectStateEntry` for the entity and compare its `CurrentValues` and `OriginalValues`. But this is mostly wrong approach. Logic should be triggered by code in the entity.

Comment: Even though the second solution is "dirty" I think I'm going to go with it. There is a bulk processing going on for some related data and it is needed to be done exactly before save. Thank you for an answer. You always provide good solutions :)